# How do I minimize C#, LINQ code in Deleting Multiple Records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Here is a method to delete zero Inventory records from Inventory Table. I would like to reduce code/no of times that `LINQ` executes on Database.

Inventory Table

```
public class Inventory
    {
        public int itemCode { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public decimal availQty { get; set; } // Can have Negative values.
    }
```

example data

```
itemCode    price       availQty
1           10           10
1           12          -10
2           10           10
```

From above records, i want to delete all records of itemCode == 1, as net availQty is 0.

Here is my method

```
private void RemoveZeroInvs()
        {
        // Remove individual zero Inventorys
            var rinvs = from ri in _context.Inventorys
                        where ri.availQty == 0
                        select ri;

            _context.Inventorys.RemoveRange(rinvs);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            // Remove if group is zero in availQty, as it allows Negative Qty.
            var result = from d in _context.Inventorys
                         group d by new
                         {
                             d.itemCode
                         }
                          into g
                         select new
                         {
                             g.Key.itemCode,
                             availQty = g.Sum(y => y.availQty)
                         };

            var zrs = from r in result
                      where r.availQty == 0
                      select r;

            foreach (var zr in zrs) // Here, zrs length may be more than 500
            {
                var ri = _context.Inventorys.Where(w => w.itemCode == zr.itemCode);
                _context.Inventorys.RemoveRange(ri);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I use `Asp.Net Core 2.2`. Is there any such possibility?

Also I get following error at line `_context.Inventorys.RemoveRange(ri);` in the loop.

```
A command is already in progress: SELECT t."itemCode", t."availQty"
FROM (
    SELECT d."itemCode", SUM(d."availQty") AS "availQty"
    FROM "Inventorys" AS d
    GROUP BY d."itemCode"
) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var todelete = _context.Inventorys
   .GroupBy(i => i.itemCode)
   .Where(g => g.Sum(i => i.availQty) == 0)
   .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Here is a shorter versions of your code, in terms of DB excecution, one would have to compare the raw queries. But it may be lighter that your code…

Comment: @Ramesh, i guess it is an unrelated issue. Did you try again ?

Comment: I tried several times, even from different PC. I could not understand what was wrong.